# Can not authenticate facebook app in docker google vm instace using passport nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, passport.js, docker-swarm, passport-facebook

Config facebook application to authenticate in google vm instance without a domain

This is for a new Linux server, running mongodb, nodejs. I've tried on localhost and sucessfully to authenticate, but in google vm instance, it's not working. I've already add my external ip of google vm instabce to whitelist server ip in faceebook app, but it still not working

In my passport.js implement passport nodejs. It's placed in config folder:

```
const FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');
const passportConfig = (passportSettings, passport) => {
    passport.use('facebookToken', new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: passportSettings.oauth.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: passportSettings.oauth.facebook.clientSecret,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    enableProof: true
    }, function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {}
}
module.exports = passportConfig;
```

Here is my index.js to run the node service. I create a passport instance and require it here. You can ignore another object as repository, userController, di, ... to make a test code:

```
'use strict'
const {EventEmitter} = require('events')
const server = require('./server/server')
const repository = require('./repository/repository')
const userControler = require('./api/users')
const di = require('./config')
const mediator = new EventEmitter()
const passport = require('passport')
const { createContainer, asValue } = require('awilix')

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Exception', err)
})

process.on('uncaughtRejection', (err, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection', err)
})

const container = createContainer()
require('./config/utils/passport')( container.resolve('passportSettings'), passport)
const passportSettings = {
  JWT_SECRET : 'codeworkrauthentication',
  oauth: {
     google: {
       clientID: 'number',
       clientSecret: 'string'
     },
     facebook: {
       clientID: 'number',
       clientSecret: 'string'
    }
  }
}
const serverSettings = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  ssl: require('./ssl')
}

container.register({
    passportSettings : asValue(passportSettings),
    serverSettings : asValue(serverSettings)
})

server.start(container)
.then(app => {
  console.log(`Server started succesfully, running on port: ${container.cradle.serverSettings.port}.`)
})
```

And here is my server.js which called in index.js file. In which i bind to authentication api:

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const helmet = require('helmet')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const _api = require('../api/authentication')

const start = (container) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const {port, ssl} = container.resolve('serverSettings')
    const repo = container.resolve('repo')
    const userControler = container.resolve('userControler')
    if (!repo) {
      reject(new Error('The server must be started with a connected repository'))
    }
    if (!port) {
      reject(new Error('The server must be started with an available port'))
    }

    const app = express()
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
    app.use(bodyparser.json())
    app.use(cors())
    app.use(helmet())
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      eject(new Error('Something went wrong!, err:' + err))
      res.status(500).send('Something went wrong!')
      next()
    })
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      req.container = container.createScope()
      next()
    })

    const api = _api.bind(null, {repo}, {userControler})
    api(app)

    const server = app.listen(port, () => resolve(server))

  })
}
```

And here is my authentication.js which include in api folder and was called in server.js. In which i call the passport instance :

```
const passport = require('passport')
const status = require('http-status')

module.exports = ({repo}, {userControler}, app) => {
    app.post('/authentication-service/signup-with-facebook',passport.authenticate('facebookToken', {session:false}), userControler.facebookOAuth);
}
```

So you can remove the config setting and set directly into the passportSetting  and serverSettings. Here is my passportSetting structure:

```
const passportSettings = {
  JWT_SECRET : 'codeworkrauthentication',
  oauth: {
     google: {
       clientID: 'number',
       clientSecret: 'string'
     },
     facebook: {
       clientID: 'number',
       clientSecret: 'string'
     }
  }
}
```

About the serverSettings that i called in server.js :

```
const serverSettings = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
  ssl: require('./ssl')
}
```

And when i run it as node app in google vm instance it's falled into error :

```
can not fetch user profile
```

As my debug. It stucked at /config/passport.js:

```
passport.use('facebookToken', new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: passportSettings.oauth.facebook.clientID,
    clientSecret: passportSettings.oauth.facebook.clientSecret,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    enableProof: true
}, function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {}
```

error code :

```
Error at passport-facebook-token/lib/index.js:155:32
```

In google cloud. I have a google vm instance which was reversed static ip and was pointed by a domain already. But it's still not working. Don't know why?

Comment: Hey, someone help me!! I can not figure out what's going on. I can not add domain to my cloud because it's in development mode. So why this happening, why facebook app block authentication in google cloud vm

Comment: Could you specify which Google Cloud product you are using? Also, if possible, do you have this code available for download so that I may try to reproduce it?  [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JKleinne. I've editted my question. In which, i summarize the server code. You can modify it and use your google cloud to run it as a node service and your facebook app as authentication service. Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry i do not have enough reputations to add image into my question to make it more understandable